# Use pipe ("|") as first symbol in bash or zsh command

Tags: bash, macos, pipe, zsh, magrittr

I have two simple scripts:

## `./cpthat`

[`BlueM/cliclick`](https://github.com/BlueM/cliclick) types on the keyboard: <kbd>Shift+Cmd+A</kbd>, then <kbd>Cmd+C</kbd>, to the active `iTerm` terminal:

```sh
#!/bin/zsh
cliclick kd:shift,cmd t:a ku:shift t:c ku:cmd
pbpaste>$THATF
```

- <kbd>Shift+Cmd+A</kbd> **selects** the *output from the previous command*, and
- <kbd>Cmd+C</kbd> **copies** "that" to the clipboard.
- `pbpaste` then **writes** that to the file $THATF defined system-wide.

## `./that`

```sh
#!/bin/zsh
cat $THATF
```

This prints out the output of the last command as stored by `cpthat`.

(I know I can run `$ command > $THATF` directly but for other reasons I need to act retroactively on the command output. Also, not thread safe.)

## The challenge:

I'm trying to get to where I can start a `zsh` or `bash` command with a pipe:

```
$ |grep -i sometext
```

Where, in effect, this happens:

```
$ that|grep -i sometext
```

Would this be possible somehow?

- Overriding the pipe operator?
- zsh config magic?
- I'm using zsh heavily but am open for any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Animation showing that `|` alone at the beginning of command can be replaced automatically by the output of previous command:

[image]

### Edit `~/.zshrc` to override zsh's `zle accept-line` widget:

```bash
readonly THATF="path/to/your/temporary/file"

my-accept-line () {  
  if [[ "${BUFFER:0:1}" == '|' ]]; then    
    /usr/local/bin/cliclick kd:shift,cmd t:a ku:shift w:100 t:c ku:cmd
    pbpaste>"${THATF}"
    BUFFER='cat ${THATF} '${BUFFER}
  fi  
  zle .accept-line
}

zle -N accept-line my-accept-line
```

#### Explanation

- When you hit `enter` after entering a command, `zsh` runs the `accept-line` widget.
- We override that widget, but before exiting we remember to call the original widget with `zle .accept-line`. With the dot prefix the factory widget is ran.
- In `iTerm2`, `shift+cmd+a` selects all the output from the previous command, and `cmd+c` copies that to the system pasteboard.
- We paste the contents of the pasteboard and redirects that to the temporary file declared earlier, pointed to by `${THATF}`.
- We prepend $BUFFER, the `zsh` special variable available within `zle widget` code, with the output of the previous command.

#### Dependencies, caveats:

This particular solution depends on:

- [`cliclick`](https://github.com/BlueM/cliclick) dispatching `macOS` keyboard events. Perhaps a native solutions exist e.g. ANSI/escape sequence.
- [`iTerm`](https://www.iterm2.com) to handle the keybind for copying last commands output.
- `zsh` for the `zle` widget.

Xode snippet above is proof-of-concept only and is wildly insecure.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to start with a `|`. The`grep` utility naturally reads `STDIN`.

Here's a contrived example:

```
# /bin/sh
# count_matches
grep $1 | wc -l

$ cat file | count_matches thing
```

You can see the `|` you're looking for is on the command line itself, not within the script

Similarly this works:

```
$ count_matches thing < file
```

In the first example, the `STDIN` is connected (via the pipe) to the output of the first command (trivially `cat`). In the second, it's from the actual file via redirection.

So, just get rid of the `|` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have used another command than `grep`. For *any* command, what I want to happen is to 1) not use any parameters referencing 'file' or 'thing' and 2) due to what I'm writing, I actually need to be able to juse write `$ | command1 | command2 | command 3 | command 4` without referencing to $THATF.

Comment: @haakonstorm: Many commands read standard input by default — `grep` as you know, but also `sed`, `awk`, `sort`, `cat`, `uniq`, `tr` (a special case; it only reads standard input), …  For many filter-like commands, the default behaviour is 'read named files if there are any; otherwise, read standard input'.  This has proven to be a sound design over many, many years.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There is nothing to read on `stdin`. As stated above, I'm *starting* my command with a pipe as the very first character. As in, `$ |command2`, and have that result in the output of the previous command being piped (via `cat` or process substitution). Getting the output of the previous command can be done with a hotkey in `iTerm` on the Mac.

Comment: @haakonstorm: OK — then if you're lucky, `zsh` defines a meaning for that (starting a command with a `|`).  If you're unlucky, `zsh` doesn't define a meaning for it.  I know of no other shell that defines a meaning for it.  All the orthodox shells expect a pipe as a separator (connector) between two commands, not as a unary prefix for a command.  Failing that, you'll have to write your own shell that gives a meaning to what you want to write.  I'm not sure why you want to write code like that.  However, that's not a major concern of mine; you may choose to do as you wish.

Comment: I found a solution, so answering my own question. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Can you post your solution?

Comment: @Will Hartung: As requested, submitted a solution by filling my own request. I'd love to hear whether you got this to run and you see the benefits! E.g: --long --1 listing a folder, or list all untracked files in a git repo, then automatically have 'fzf' provide you an interface to cherrypick from those lists - with fzf itself providing a background choir of singing elves and glorious regexp support - and do whatever you like with what you selected.